# How can I specify java.library.path for an app built with sbt native packager?

Tags: java, windows, scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

This is on Windows, so the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not usable.

I tried `batScriptExtraDefines` but it does not pickup the setting.

I tried creating the `src/universal/<APP_ENV_NAME>_config.txt` file, replacing \ with the `name` specified in build.sbt, but it still does not pickup the config. I am not sure how to setup this APP_ENV_NAME since it is just briefly mentioned in the document.

I tried `javaOptions in Universal` but it does not pickup the setting.

Is there any other suggestion how to tackle this problem?

Comment: There is also another document that says in Windows, the variable PATH is used instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I will update when I try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, instead of setup the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, `PATH` environment variable is instead used to find paths to the native libraries.

```
set PATH=%PATH%;<path to your native libraries>
```